# Is there a temporary way to prevent two maloccluding teeth from impacting one another?

Tags: dentistry

If one's bite is bad and two teeth are constantly impacting one another causing pain problems, is there an advisable way to prevent impact from constantly occurring, for example, with a squishy, gummy piece of rubber which can be held between the teeth? (Prior to getting real orthodontics).

My prior research has been asking a dental hygienist who responded in the negative and googling "prevent teeth from impacting" or similar but with often results on topics I wasn't looking for due to keyword mismatch.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. Have you done any research on this? What did you find? If you found nothing, what did you search for? We require questions here to demonstrate at least some basic prior research.

Comment: Impaction is a wrong word. Google the word 'plunger cusp' and then let us know whether you mean the same